# how to update the phone number in firebase at authentication

Tags: ios

how to update the phone number in firebase.I have added a phone number in authentication.And login in with this phone number .Now i need to update the phone number.How to update the phone in firebase in authentication.

My CURRent code is :-if  let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser{

```
    guard let vertificationid =  userDefault.string(forKey: "vertificationId") else {return}

        let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: vertificationid, verificationCode: self.phoneno!)
        currentUser.updatePhoneNumber(credential, completion: { (error) in

          if  error  == nil{
            print(error)
        }

     })

  }
```

i don't know whether it is correct or not?

Comment: how to update the phone number in the firebase at authentication

Comment: Are u solve it?